# How to use if statement to compare variable with multiple values in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, comparison

I am trying to make an if statement that checks to see if a variable is not equal to multiple different values.

Here's my code:

```
for subID in {1..100}
    if [ "${subID}" != 2 8 34 56 89 92 ]
        echo "Yes"
    else
        echo "No"
    fi
done
```

I get an error saying that there are too many arguments.  Is there a way to code for this completely within the if statement, or should I just set the values I want to compare as a separate variable using a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `case` statement

```
for subID in {1..100}; do
    case $subID in 
        2|8|34|56|89|92) echo "Yes" ;;
        *)               echo "No" ;;
    esac
done
```

or bash extended globbing

```
shopt -s extglob
for subID in {1..100}; do
    if [[ $subID == @(2|8|34|56|89|92) ]]; then
        echo Yes
    else
        echo No
    fi
done
```